# Not receiving data from ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send data from javascript to another php page where I want to display it. I found that I need to use Ajax to pass the data to php so I tried myself.

My file where is the javascript:

```
    $('#button').on('click', function () {
  $.jstree.reference('#albero').select_all();
  var selectedElmsIds = [];
  var selectedElmsIds = $('#albero').jstree("get_selected", true);
  var i = 0;
  $.each(selectedElmsIds, function() {
    var nomenodo = $('#albero').jstree('get_selected', true)[i].text;
    //var idnodo = selectedElmsIds.push(this.id);
    var livellonodo = $('#albero').jstree('get_selected', true)[i].parents.length;
    //console.log("ID nodo: " + selectedElmsIds.push(this.id) + " Nome nodo: " + $('#albero').jstree('get_selected', true)[i].text);
    //console.log("Livello: " + $('#albero').jstree('get_selected', true)[i].parents.length);
    i++;
    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 'namenodo': nomenodo,
                    'levelnodo': livellonodo
                          },
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $("#content").html(data);
                    }
                });
  });
});
```

I want to send the data to another php page which consists of:

```
<?php echo $_POST["namenodo"]; ?>
```

But when I try to go to the page there's no data displayed.

Comment: Actually you cannot see it from `lamiadownline.php`

Comment: There is no way to see or send it to the page?

Comment: You can send it to the other page, but you cannot view it from there. If you want to view it, you need to change your `success:` a little

Comment: Put `console.log(data)` in the `success` handler to see the response.

Comment: If I put the data in console.log it display me all the data from the page and not the level or the name of the node. The reason I want to get the level of all the nodes is because I wanted to use them in the php page to put them in a table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic mistake I think every beginner (including me) does while posting a data using ajax to another php page.

Your ajax code is actually posting the data to lamiadownline.php (if you are using the variables correctly) but you can't get that data by simply using echo.

Ajax post method post data to your php page (lamiadownline.php) but when you want to echo the same data on the receiver page (lamiadownline.php), you are actually reloading the lamiadownline.php page again which makes the $_POST["namenodo"] value null.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you won't be able to see what you have post by browsing to that page.

Secondly, is this

```
<?php echo $_POST["namenodo"]; ?>
```

in the current page?

Otherwise, specify the url

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "lamiadownline.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: { 'namenodo': nomenodo,
         'levelnodo': livellonodo},
     success: function(data) {
         $("#content").html(data);
     }
 });
```

Comment: No it is in another php page.

Comment: Specify the url then.

Answer (score 0):

//try this

$.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url:"Your_php_page.php"
                             data: { namenodo: nomenodo levelnodo: livellonodo},
                                success: function(data)
                           {
                        $("#content").html(data);
                    }
                });